# How to create an array of byte arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I want to create an array of `byte[]`.
When i try:

```
byte[] data = new byte[10];
```

This is an array of `byte` and not an array of `byte[]`.
Thanks

Comment: `byte[][] data = new byte[10][10]` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To address some confusion about "arrays of arrays" and 2D arrays:

Java doesn't really have 2D arrays.  At least, not in the way many people think of them, where  they look like a matrix, and you have rows and columns and the same number of elements in each row.

You *can* use an "array of arrays" as a 2D array.  If you want an array of 5 x 8 integers, you can say

```
int[][] arr = new int[5][8];
```

But Java does not enforce the "matrix-ness" or "2D-ness" of an array.  What it gives you is an array of 5 references, each of which refers to another array of integers.  Each reference starts out referring to an array of 8 integers, but this is not enforced; you could later say

```
arr[2] = new int[113];
```

or

```
arr[2] = null;
```

and now your array is no longer really a 2D array (as we usually think of it), but Java will not stop you from doing that.

So while you may often see something like

```
byte[][]
```

used in textbooks to create a 2D array, it's the same syntax as an array of arrays, and Java actually treats it as an array of arrays, not all of which have to be the same size.

If you want to create an array whose elements *will eventually be* arrays, but that are `null` for now, you can do it like this:

```
byte[][] bytesArray = new byte[10][];
```

which sets `bytesArray` to an array of 10 `null` references, any one of which could be set later:

```
bytesArray[4] = new byte[17];
```

That would be the way to start, if you want a "ragged array" of arrays that aren't all the same length.

Answer (score 5):

In Java, an array where each element is itself an array is effectively just a 2D array, although Java doesn't require that each row have the same number of elements.

In this particular case where you have a `List<byte[]>` and you wish to turn that into an array where each element of the array is itself a `byte` array you could use:

```
int rows = myList.size();
byte[][] myArray = new byte[rows][];

int i = 0;
for (byte[] col : myList) {
    myArray[i++] = col;
}
```

or, more succinctly, but less obviously:

```
byte[][] myArray = myList.toArray(new byte[0][]);
```

which in use looks like:

```
List<byte[]> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(new byte[]{1,2,3,4});
myList.add(new byte[]{5,6,7});
myList.add(new byte[]{8,9});

byte[][] myArray = myList.toArray(new byte[0][]);

for (byte[] b : myArray) {
    for (byte c : b) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Note that in both cases above the elements of the array are *exactly* the same arrays as those stored in the list, not a copy.  Therefore if you modify one of the original `byte[]` elements in the list it'll also change the version accessible via the array.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

byte[][] arrays = new byte[5][10];

Comment: This is a 2D array. I want an array of byte[], like you can do an array of int.

Comment: @Alex that's what an array of `byte[]` is - a 2D array

Comment: @Alnitak No!!, i have a List<byte[]> and i want to conver this to an array. So i should create an array of byte[] , and i don't want 2D array. Simple question

Comment: array of array is a2d array.

Comment: @Alex everyone here is telling you the same thing, and they are correct: an array of arrays is a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Like this? Foo[] array = list.toArray(new Foo[list.size()]);

Comment: @SamuelePanarotto Edit your answer to change `Byte` to `byte` and I'll upvote your answer, as it is otherwise correct. (And hopefully the three downvoters will copy suit, or at least explain themselves.)

Comment: @SamuelePanarotto the OP is using `byte`, not `Byte` - not sure how to use `.toArray` (if indeed it's possible) with a primitive.

Comment: To the OP, when you change your answer (because it's wrong) you should note that in the comments so that down votes can be modified (if appropriate)

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
byte[][] data = new byte[][]{byteArray1, byteArray2, byteArray3};
```

Comment: Like this:
byte[] _______ byteArray = {-119, -8, -113, 118,  -127}

Comment: @Alex you appear confused - what you've just written is a 1D array of `byte`, not an array of `byte[]`

Comment: This answer does describe an "array of byte arrays", exactly as requested in your question.

Comment: What you just described is an array of byte, not byte[]. An array of byte[] is just a 2D array

Comment: @Alnitak if i make byte[][] is 2D array and not 1D array of byte[].

Comment: @Alex yes, because that's what an array of `byte[]` is - a 2D array!  I shall re-open your question and elaborate

Comment: @Alex I just saw that you want to convert a List<byte[]> to an array of arrays. In this case what you want is a 2D array, which is the same thing as an array of arrays

Comment: @Alex In Java there is no difference between an "array of arrays" and a 2D array.  There are some languages that have separate concepts for those two things, but Java is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are creating an array of bytes, if you wanted to create an array of arrays of bytes you would have to create a two dimensional array of bytes:

`byte[][] bytesArray = new byte[10][10];`

You would then be able to access your array of bytes as follows:

`bytesArray[0]; // returns a byte[]`

Comment: I want array of byte[]. byte[] is the type!!